# When finding a route using Dijkstra's algorithm via a node, can I double back?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

For a given graph, let us say that the shortest route is $A-B-C$.
However, we must travel via the node $D$.
If we are allowed to double back, the shortest route would be $A-B-D-B-C$. Otherwise, we would have to use the route $A-B-D-E-C$, which is longer.

Is it acceptable to double back as stated above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that, although Dijkstra's algorithm does not allow us to go through the same node twice, as would be expected, when it comes to adjusting the route to go via a given node, we can indeed do the suggested if it still gives the shortest route. @Stefan4024 's method is ideal for proving this.

Answer (score 3):

Dijkstra's algorithm doesn't allow you to go through a same vertex twice. In fact coming back full circle is not going to be optimal after all, so there's not need to spend time on checking that route.

Anyway given a constrain that we need to pass through $D$ you can adjust the algorithm. I would recommend splitting the problem into two subproblems. First find the shortest route from $A$ to $D$ and then from $D$ to $C$. Of course this will give you the shortest route from $A$ to $C$ via $D$.